# TYPO3 Extbase: access $BE_USER

Tags: typo3, extbase

How can I access the $BE_USER variable inside my Extbase controller on the front-end? I just want to know the back-end user ID which is logged in.

http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_api/4.1.0/view/3/6/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$GLOBALS['BE_USER']` ... you are still in the normal `TYPO3` backend context and you can access any global variable. Just make sure that you only read that array/object of you are really in backend mode.